# Why does index contraction have to be done between upper and lower indices?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation, covariance

If I had to give a guess based on limited understanding, I would expect it to be something to do with the resulting object no longer obeying tensor transformation properties.

However, if that is the case I have one further question. If I contract the indices of a (2,0)-tensor I obtain a scalar, which is (by definition?) a well behaved tensor. Why is this operation invalid? Or is it not invalid, it just doesn't return a meaningful object?

Comment: Your title correctly states that contraction occurs between an upper and a lower index. Then in the body you talk about contracting two upper (or does (2,0) mean two lower) indices. This is inconsistent. You need to write some math to show what you are talking about.

Comment: Ah no I mean that as a counterexample, I understand contraction of a (2,0)-tensor is wrong, what I really mean is "if I sum the components of a (2,0)-tensor in the same way...", that might be unclear from how I've worded it.

Comment: The short answer is that only by contracting an upper and a lower index do you get a tensor of lower rank.

Comment: You don’t obtain a scalar when you contract two upper or two lower indices. A scalar is not just something that has only one component (i.e., just a number). It has to be a number that transforms into itself.

Comment: I see it written a lot that you shouldn't get too hung up on thinking of tensors as arrays of numbers, but if I take for instance the Euclidian metric and just take the trace I obtain a number. So I take $g_\mu\nu$ and sum over $g_\mu\mu$, that gives me a number when I think of the components as numbers in an array, but this operation is illegal, but I still obtain a scalar? My question is how is that different to the scalar obtained from the contraction of, say, $M^i_j \rightarrow M^i_i$?

Comment: The difference is that contraction between upper and lower indices is not a simple sum but rather $M^\mu_{\,\,\,\mu}=g_{\mu\nu}M^{\mu\nu}$. This results in a scalar under transformations, while taking the trace does not.

Comment: Am I right in saying that contraction is a sum when the metric is the Euclidean metric, but in general it is not?

Comment: Contraction is a simple sum of the appropriate upper-lower components: $M^\mu{}_\mu= M^0{}_0+M^1{}_1+M^2{}_2+ M^3{}_3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider a simple *explicit* example of how contracting two upper Lorentz indices or two lower indices doesn't produce a Lorentz invariant.

A particle has energy and momentum. The particle can be observed in two different inertial frames which might be moving relative to one another. In one frame the energy is $E$ and the momentum is $\mathbf{p}=(p^x,p^y,p^z)$. In another frame the energy is $E'$ and the momentum is $\mathbf{p}'=(p'^x,p'^y,p'^z)$.

I'm writing the $x$, $y$, and $z$ as *superscripts* to be consistent with the four-vector notation that I'll introduce in a bit.

The Lorentz transformations ensure that the particular combination $E^2-\mathbf{p}^2$ is *invariant*. In other words

$$E'^2-\mathbf{p}'^2=E^2-\mathbf{p}^2$$

in units where $c=1$. For example, the Lorentz transformation of energy and momentum when the primed frame is moving with velocity $v\hat{x}$ relative to the unprimed frame is

$$E'=\gamma(E-vp^x)$$
$$p'^x=\gamma(p^x-vE)$$
$$p'^y=p^y$$
$$p'^z=p^z$$

where $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2}$.

You can verify with a little algebra that for this particular transformation

$$E'^2-(p'^x)^2-(p'^y)^2-(p'^z)^2=E^2-(p^x)^2-(p^y)^2-(p^z)^2$$

You can similarly verify that $E^2+\mathbf{p}^2$ (with a *plus* sign) is *not* an invariant. (In fact $E^2-\mathbf{p}^2$ is the *only* quadratic Lorentz invariant that can be formed from the energy and the momentum.)

So, what does this have to do with tensors and contraction?

The contravariant energy-momentum four-vector is defined to be

$$p^\mu=(E,p^x,p^y,p^z)$$

and (in Minkowski space with signature +---) the covariant version of this is

$$p_\mu=(E,-p^x,-p^y,-p^z).$$

Now consider three tensors -- $p^\mu p^\nu$, $p_\mu p_\nu$, and $p^\mu p_\nu$  -- and look at what happens when we try to contract the two indices of each one.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_\mu p^\mu p^\mu&=p^0p^0+p^1p^1+p^2p^2+p^3p^3=E^2+(p^x)^2+(p^y)^2+(p^z)^2\\
&=E^2+\mathbf{p}^2\quad\text{NOT AN INVARIANT!}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_\mu p_\mu p_\mu&=p_0p_0+p_1p_1+p_2p_2+p_3p_3=E^2+(p^x)^2+(p^y)^2+(p^z)^2\\
&=E^2+\mathbf{p}^2\quad\text{NOT AN INVARIANT!}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_\mu p^\mu p_\mu&=p^0p_0+p^1p_1+p^2p_2+p^3p_3=E^2-(p^x)^2-(p^y)^2-(p^z)^2\\
&=E^2-\mathbf{p}^2\quad\text{AN INVARIANT!}
\end{align}$$

The lesson is that contracting two upper indices or two lower indices does *not* produce a Lorentz invariant, while contracting an upper and a lower *does* produce a Lorentz invariant. (If there are additional indices, it instead produces a tensor whose rank is lower by 2.)

This is why when using Lorentz index notation, we *never* contract two upper or two lower indices. It doesn't produce a valid tensor! (Remember: Tensors are not just indexed quantities. They have to obey *very specific transformation rules* when the coordinates are transformed.)

This is not a general proof that contracting an upper and a lower index produces an invariant or a lower-rank tensor. You can find that in any textbook, using the properties of a general Lorentz transformation $\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$. Instead, this is a concrete example to make what happens in one simple case really explicit.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this, my mistake was thinking that any scalar is lorentz invariant just by nature.

Answer (score 1):

Under coordinate transformations, vectors transform with the Jacobi matrix, whereas covectors transform with its inverse. If you contract an upper and a lower index, these operations cancel, and the result will be invariant under coordinate transformations.

In contrast, summing over two indices in the same position generally won't give you an invariant. Take two-dimensional Euclidean space as an example. In Cartesian coordinates, the metric tensor is just the unit matrix, with a trace of $2$. In polar coordinates, the angular matrix element takes up a factor of $r^2$, yielding a trace of $1+r^2$.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this operation invalid? Or is it not invalid, it just doesn't return a meaningful object?

The point is that a scalar isn't just any real number, it's a real number which transforms between frames appropriately. (Specifically, the correct transformation is that it *shouldn't* transform at all.)

For example, "the energy of a ball" isn't a scalar, even though it's a real number, because it depends on the frame, when a scalar shouldn't. "The mass of a ball", however, is a scalar. If you break the usual rules of contraction, you will get real numbers, but they won't be scalars.